# Is there a __new__ equivalent for C++?

Tags: c++, new-operator

The [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) override in Python allows you to construct an object of a completely different class using the constructor of one class. Was wondering if there was any way to achieve this in C++, or any other language for that matter? Writing a certain solving software, originally in Python, then moved to Java for speed reasons and also clarity of structure, and had a pseudo way of achieving this for Java, but since C++ is more flexible and versatile maybe the real thing might be possible. Thanks the consideration

Comment: Direct translations between languages almost never turn out well. It doesn't matter if it's programming, spoken or written languages. The best way to "translate" a program is to reimplement the design.

Comment: Avoid any new/delete in C++ nowadays anyway.

Comment: I am not sure if moving to Java from Python for performance reasons is reasonable.

Comment: @nada: Java's multi-threading design is significantly ahead of Python. It's literally so good that C++ stole its threading model outright back in 2003.

Answer (score 5):

Memory for an object is allocated before the constructor is called.

And since C++ is not a dynamically typed system, you cannot change the type of the object at runtime.

Use a factory function instead.

Answer (score 0):

A literal translation of what you want to do would probably go like this:

```cpp
class A {};
class B {};
class C {};

void* create_object(char class_letter) {
    switch (class_letter) {
        case 'A': return new A;
        case 'B': return new B;
        case 'C': return new C;
        default: return new A;
    }
}
```

Everyone who had his first C++ lessons including the usual recommendations knows this is bound to explode. Why? Look: You could call this function like this:

```cpp
void* ptr = create_object('B');
```

You get a `void*` which is not a nice thing to have, because now it's your duty to cast it to the correct type for example by doing:

```cpp
B* b_ptr = (B*)ptr; // eww!
```

and equally important - now it's also your duty to `delete` it (yuck!), which is a popular thing us coders tend to forget.

---

**Bottom line is, it's doable - as always, but ugly. So use a different design pattern if you plan on implementing this in C++.**

Comment: Didn't get your point. You showed unsafe design and then said that it is bad. This same scheme could be implemented with common base class, `std::unique_ptr` and `dynamic_cast` or with templates without any issues.

Comment: @sklott Of course. You can expand on my answer if you feel like it. Just wanted to keep it basic and simple. There is also `std::variant` and probably much much more which could be useful to OP. C++ is a powerful tool.